# Trouble converting a date to a string and passing to SQL

Tags: vb.net

I'm getting the following error message:

> **System.InvalidCastException:** Conversion from string "select * from [tbl_FBNK_Limit_Hi" to type 'Integer' is not valid.

My setup is really pretty simple. Here is all the code:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1

    'Change Path Here:
    Dim connString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=path_here.accdb"
    Dim MyConn As OleDbConnection
    Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ds As DataSet
    Dim tables As DataTableCollection
    Dim source1 As New BindingSource
    Dim SqlStr As String
    Dim startDate As String
    Dim endDate As String

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        MyConn = New OleDbConnection
        MyConn.ConnectionString = connString
        ds = New DataSet
        tables = ds.Tables

        Dim startDate As DateTime = DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
        Dim endDate As DateTime = DateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")

        SqlStr = "select * from [tbl_Hist_Current] where AsOfDate >= #" & startDate & "# and AsOfDate <=#" & endDate & "#"

        da = New OleDbDataAdapter(SqlStr, MyConn)
        da.Fill(SqlStr, "tbl_Limit_Hist_Current")
        Dim view As New DataView(tables(0))
        source1.DataSource = view
        DataGridView1.DataSource = view
    End Sub    
End Class
```

When I copy/paste the `SqlStr` into Access it works fine, so it's gotta be something with the way the dates are being handled, or not handled. Can someone here give me a nudge in the right direction?

```
Private Sub LoadData_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=server_name;Initial Catalog=database_name;Integrated Security=True"
    Dim SqlStr As String
    Dim startDate As DateTime = DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
    Dim endDate As DateTime = DateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")

    SqlStr = "Select Field1, Field2, Field3, AsOfDate FROM [TBL_DATA_HIST] where AsOfDate >= '" & startDate & "' and AsOfDate <='" & endDate & "'"

    Dim connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    Dim dataadapter As New SqlDataAdapter(SqlStr, connection)
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    connection.Open()
    dataadapter.Fill(ds, "TBL_DATA_HIST")
    connection.Close()
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
    DataGridView1.DataMember = "TBL_DATA_HIST"

    ' Count rows in DG
    Dim int As Integer
    int = DataGridView1.Rows.Count()
    TextBox1.Text = int

End Sub
```

Comment: First, **never** concat values into strings to make SQL, use SQL parameters.  Then, the NET providers are perfectly capable of passing a DateTime type parameter to your DB.  (of course the date data should also be stored as a date in the DB for them to act like a date)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following solution, using [parameter placeholders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataadapter-parameters#oledb-parameter-placeholders):

```
'Change Path Here:
Dim connString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=path_here.accdb"
Dim MyConn As OleDbConnection
Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
Dim ds As DataSet
Dim tables As DataTableCollection
Dim source1 As New BindingSource
Dim SqlStr As String
Dim startDate As String
Dim endDate As String

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    MyConn = New OleDbConnection
    MyConn.ConnectionString = connString

    Dim startDate As DateTime = DateTimePicker1.Value
    Dim endDate As DateTime = DateTimePicker2.Value

    SqlStr = "select * from [tbl_Limit_Hist_Current] where AsOfDate >= ? and AsOfDate <= ?"

    da = New OleDbDataAdapter(SqlStr, MyConn)
    Dim selectCMD As New OleDbCommand(SqlStr, MyConn)
    da.SelectCommand = selectCMD

    selectCMD.Parameters.Add("@AsOfDate1", OleDbType.Date).Value = startDate
    selectCMD.Parameters.Add("@AsOfDate2", OleDbType.Date).Value = endDate

    ds = New DataSet
    da.Fill(ds, "tbl_Limit_Hist_Current")
    tables = ds.Tables
    Dim view As New DataView(tables(0))
    source1.DataSource = view
    DataGridView1.DataSource = view
End Sub
```

You should also remove the `ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")` on the `DateTimePicker` values. On my system (german setup - `dd.mm.yyyy` date format by default) I got an error message like the following:

> Invalid conversion of the string 11.13.2017 to type Date - *translated from german*

As Joel Coehoorn also [mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47269691/trouble-converting-a-date-to-a-string-and-passing-to-sql/47270014#comment81491369_47270014), is it a performance waste and in some situations a security issue.

Comment: Exactly. I might structure my code a little differently, but Parameters are the important thing here and the _**only**_ right way to do this. If you ever find yourself wanting to convert a date to a string for SQL, that's a **HUGE** red flag you're doing something wrong. Additionally, parameters are not just for date values. _All_ user information should be sent to the database using parameters.

Comment: That said, you really out to remove the `ToString()` from the DateTimePicker entirely. That's a performance waste, and in some situations it's a security issue, since users can alter parts of how their system creates the date time strings, up to and including adding arbitrary text.

Comment: Yes I see you removed it. That's fine! If I run this on my PC (german setup), I got an error with the `ToString` because the formatted date can't be assigned to the DateTime variables. So I got the following error (german): System.InvalidCastException: "Ungültige Konvertierung von der Zeichenfolge 11.13.2017 in Typ Date."